# Sudo not working as expected via LDAP

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ldap

I have provisioned an IP server with sudo rules associated with a group. But on a relying host, `sudo -l` returns `Sorry, user symcbean may not run sudo on host.example.com`. I have logged in as user from the LDAP repository.

The relying host is running Ubuntu 20.04.

My `nsswitch.conf` file contains...

```
sudoers:        ldap files
```

The URI and BASdn in `/etc/sudo-ldap.conf` is the same as in `/etc/ldap.conf`

`sssd` is not installed. `nscd` is installed.

I have a `sudo` rule `ALL` allowing all members of `example-admins` to run any command on any host. My account is a member of this group.

I have replaced the `sudo` package with `sudo-ldap`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the user actually in `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d`?

Comment: Does the `sudo-ldap` package look for the sudoers file rules in LDAP instead of local files?

Comment: In `sudoers` are you using `%example-admins` or `+example-admins` to identify the group rule? If you're using `%` prefix try changing it to `+`. If that works I'll provide an answer

Comment: It's been some years ago, but I recall needing to adjust the cache settings in my `nscd` config file or it would cache negative and positive answers for too long.